# Java Bukkit - plugin cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, eclipse, bukkit

I really need help with this.
I tried a lot of suggestions online from a google search but I didn't get much. Some solutions I tried to come up with myself were:

```
public LunarCore plugin = new LunarCore();
```

but I don't know for sure if that will work.
Here is my code

```
IconMenu menu = new IconMenu("Idle Menu", 9, new IconMenu.OptionClickEventHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onOptionClick(IconMenu.OptionClickEvent event) {
        event.getPlayer().sendMessage("You have chosen " + event.getName());
        event.setWillClose(true);
    }
}, plugin)
.setOption(3, new ItemStack(Material.GOLD_INGOT, 1), "Shop")
```

And obviously it is on

```
        }
}, plugin)
```

"plugin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is a class seperated from your main-class, try

```
private Plugin plugin;

public InventoryClassName(Plugin plugin){

this.plugin = plugin;

}
```

and then pass on "this" as parameter when accessing the class through your main-class